# Determine if a range is contained within a set of ranges

Tags: c

I have a set of ranges within an array. For example (but note that my set of ranges will be larger than this):

```
static const Section arr[] = {
    {
        .start_addr = 0,
        .length = 100,
    },
    {
        .start_addr = 150,
        .length = 25,   
    },
    {
        .start_addr = 175,
        .length = 25,   
    },

    ...
}
```

The data is not necessarily sorted, and the types will all be integer types. Also, the address will never be negative, so that can be a `uint32_t`.

I then want to query whether another range would be contained within the union of all of these ranges via a function such as:

```
bool isEncapsulated(uint32_t addr, size_t len){
    // Here I need some sort of algorithm to determine whether 
    // it is fully encapsulated. 
}
```

The primary difficulty I'm having is finding a way to account for the fact that the range provided may fall over the boundary of two defined ranges. eg. if `start_addr = 170, length = 10` where it falls over the boundary of two of the defined ranges.

Is there an elegant way of achieving this?

Edit:

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gTex.jpg) a graphical depiction of what I'm trying to do. Essentially the ranges 1, 2, 3 are what I will be defining in my array. I will then be requesting whether or not any of the ranges A-F are encapsulated within it. So, D and E are the only two that aren't. I don't just want overlap, I want the range to be fully contained within the predefined ranges.

Comment: This is the "overlapping intervals" algorithm or it's variation. Google it up.

Comment: Step 1 easy: insure `addr >= arr[i].start_addr` for all `i`.

Comment: A _portable_ answer would be easier if `addr` and `len` were the same type or at least the same _sign-ness_. else there are many corner cases with `int/size_t`.

Comment: Is the data in `arr` reliably sorted by start address, or merely coincidentally sorted in the sample data?  Do any of the ranges in the data overlap, or are they all disjoint, even though some ranges are adjacent?  Again, the sample data hints at "all disjoint", but it could be misleading.  And are the types are integer types so we don't have to deal with floating point issues?  The answers to these questions critically affect the possible algorithms.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good point.  "within the union of all of these ranges" can be interpreted different ways.

Comment: Tyler, Should `start_addr = 170, length = 10` result in `true` or `false` and explain why.

Comment: Also, if the data isn't conveniently organized, then you should determine how often you'll be searching and decide whether it is worth the effort to preprocess the array into a sorted array of disjoint, non-contiguous intervals, so the search becomes easy — find the largest start less than equal to the one being searched for (binary search) and check that it covers the entire interval.  You might note the smallest start and largest end addresses, and the biggest size.  If your candidate interval is too big or falls outside the range of possibly valid addresses, you can eliminate it quickly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The data is not necessarily sorted, and the types will all be integer types. Also, the address will never be negative, so that can be a `uint32_t`, my bad.

Comment: @chux `start_addr = 170, length = 10` should return `true` because the two sections `.start_addr = 150, ...  .start_addr = 175` will fully contain it.

Comment: Given the 'not sorted' and 'not disjoint' aspects, then I think you'd probably do best to process the list to make an ordered set of the ranges covered by the static constant array — making each range in that list maximal and not contiguous with any other range.  That then makes the searching relatively straight-forward.  The build time for the optimized list is not extortionate, but not trivial either, at least, not if there are a lot of overlapping or contiguous ranges (and if you can find range 1000:100, then later 1200:100, and then later again 1100:100, that complicates the build).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The primary difficulty I'm having is finding a way to account for the fact that the range provided may fall over the boundary of two defined ranges

It is even worse.  A range may fall over many defined ranges and the order is interrogation may divide up what is left to match.  Consider the below where the `x` range is first found in `a`.  Later the left portion of `x` needs to match `b` and the right portion needs to match `c`

```
Range:      xxxxxxxxxxxx
Def range 1 ___aaaaaa___
Def range 2 bbb_________
Def range 3 _________ccc
```

Some  lightly tested code.  The main idea to to take the left and right address in range `addr/len` and test those in each section.  If it is trivially  all to one side, continue with next section.  Otherwise, shorten `addr/len`.  This possibly may divide into 2 portions. Then continue with the next section.

```
typedef struct {
  int start_addr;
  size_t length;
} Section;

// Is point `a` in the section?
// return left:-1, right:1, else 0
static int LeftInRight(intmax_t a, const Section *sec) {
  if (a < sec->start_addr) return -1;
  if (a >= sec->start_addr + (intmax_t) sec->length) return 1;
  return 0;
}

bool isEncapsulated_helper(intmax_t addr, size_t len, const Section *sec, size_t n) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    if (len == 0) return true;
    int LSide =  LeftInRight(addr, &sec[i]);
    if (LSide > 0) continue;  // all of addr/len is to the right of this section
    int RSide =  LeftInRight(addr + (intmax_t) (len - 1), &sec[i]);
    if (RSide < 0) continue;  // all of addr/len is to the left of this section

    if (LSide < 0) {
      // portion of addr/len is to the left of this section
      intmax_t Laddr = addr;
      size_t Llen = (size_t) (sec[i].start_addr - addr);
      if (!isEncapsulated_helper(Laddr, Llen, sec + 1, n-i-1)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    if (RSide <= 0) return true;
    // portion of addr/len is to the right of this section, continue with that
    intmax_t Raddr = sec[i].start_addr + (intmax_t) sec[i].length;
    size_t Rlen = (size_t) (addr + (intmax_t) len - Raddr);
    addr = Raddr;
    len = Rlen;
  }
  return len == 0;
}
```

Test code

```
static const Section arr[] = { // x
    { .start_addr = 0, .length = 100, }, // x
    { .start_addr = 150, .length = 25, }, // x
    { .start_addr = 175, .length = 25, }, };

#define SECTION_N (sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0])

bool isEncapsulated(int addr, size_t len) {
  return isEncapsulated_helper(addr, len, arr, SECTION_N);
}

int main() {
  printf("%d\n", isEncapsulated(170,10));
}
```

Comment: Note: if the sections are ordered by `addr` `if (!isEncapsulated_helper(Laddr, Llen, sec + 1, n-i-1)) {` simplifies to `if (1) {` Allowing the computation to complete in O(n) .

Answer (score 2):

If there aren't many intervals and you just want to get the job done without thinking about algorithms, just search the array linearly in `O(n)`. If the intervals in the list don't overlap, sort them and use [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) (`O(log n)`). If they overlap, [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) is the usual data structure to choose (again `O(log n)`), but it would be simpler to merge overlapping or adjacent intervals and do a binary search.

If your addresses are really small integers, and `O(log n)` is too slow for you (wait, what?), you can use an array filled with all used addresses to trade a bunch of space for `O(1)` answers to your question, but it's unlikely you'll need to going this path.

You can either merge adjacent ranges during preprocessing (i.e. create the union before hand), or you will just have to handle this special case.

Comment: Pre-processing the `const arr[]` makes sense.